# Matlab: how do I apply a function along one dimension of an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, multidimensional-array, apply

I have an array of mxnx4 dimensions and a function with a 4-element vector input. I want to apply my function to give me an mxnx4 output, such that the function is applied mxn times (i.e. the 3rd dimension of my array becomes in the input of my function). Any ideas on how do do this would be massively appreciated. I have looked at arrayfun, but this seems not to address what I want to do. I also want to maintain the formatting of my function as it requires this formatting elsewhere in my code.

I.e.:

```
F=@(V)[V(1)+V(2);V(2)+V(3); V(3)+V(4); V(4)+V(1)]
```

to be applied to array M of dimensions 2x3x4 (m=2; n=3)

```
M = zeros(2,3,4);
M(:,:,1) = [1 2 3;4 5 6];
M(:,:,2) = [7 8 9;10 11 12];
M(:,:,3) = [13 14 15; 16 17 18];
M(:,:,4) = [19 20 21; 22 23 24];
```

to generate an array of dimensions 2x3x4

```
C(1,1,:) = F([1 7 13 19])
C(1,2,:) = F([2 8 14 20])
```

etc.

I can see a for loop would work, applying the following across the mxn matrix

```
C(m,n,:)=F(M(m,n,:))
```

However, I need to run this millions of times so would like a faster approach

Comment: perhaps you should give examples of small input and output. As I understand it, you actually have 2 inputs, a 4x1 vector, and m x n x 4 array (like an RGBA image, height m and width n)

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks so much.

Comment: It's very much like what you say: I have the value of four variables for each cell within an mxn matrix. Each variable acts as an input for my function F. I want to be able to apply the function for each cell within my mxn matrix then combine to produce an mxnx4 array. Does this make more sense

Comment: a good idea is to edit your answer to clarify. Because you just asked it, and nobody has had time to respond, you can just edit and change to make it clearer. If you later want to edit, after getting replies, its good to put a note in your edited answer that it has been edited. To clarify your question, maybe put example inputs and outputs. Say a 1x4 vector, and a 6x5x4 matrix. Write out the actual elements. Then write the 6x5x4 matrix output. Then it should be clearer what you are after.

Comment: Thank you, have updated

Comment: "would like a faster approach" Did you implement the loop and found it to be a bottleneck in your code, or are you assuming it's going to be slow without actually trying it out? Loops in MATLAB are not necessarily slow. If this indeed is a bottleneck, you'll have to vectorize your function `F`, there is no way around that.

Comment: Is "bsxfun" of any use to you ?